# in Linux kernel, is the following way right to create a real-time kthread?

Tags: multithreading, linux-kernel, scheduled-tasks, real-time, scheduler

In Linux kernel, thread schedule is as real time ones(such as SCHED_FIFO) and normal ones(SCHED_NORMAL).

If I want to create a real-time thread, how to do this?  I guess like:

> 1,kthread_create
>
> 2,give the thread a real time scheduler
>
> 3,assign a real time priority

Does this fine for a real-time kthread?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the thread itself, call:

```
struct sched_param param = { .sched_priority = prio };
sched_setscheduler(current, SCHED_FIFO, &param);
```

where `prio` is the priority you want.

Comment: Sorry but I'm very unimpressed with this answser: the _syntax_ for how to set a kthread's priority really doesn't answer the question as stated.  A prio value of 1 is required to get a real-time thread, and we don't have any answer here for how to do this in non-GPL modules (since sched_setscheduler() is EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL).

Comment: All priority values under a `SCHED_FIFO` scheduling policy are real-time.